# Convert digest strings into byte strings

Tags: ruby, string, hash

Suppose I hash a filename as such

```
require 'digest'
hashed = Digest::SHA256.digest("test")
path = "/myFile/%s" %hashed
p path
```

This would give me a path equal to

```
/myFile/\x9F\x86\xD0\x81\x88L}e\x9A/\xEA\xA0\xC5Z\xD0\x15\xA3\xBFO\e+\v\x82,\xD1]l\x15\xB0\xF0\n\b"
```

This isn't what I want. Instead, I want the bytes to be literally represented as a string. The hash of `"test"` is `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`, and my desired path is

```
/myFile/9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for in the module is [`hexdigest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) - see the example at the top of [that page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html).

So your code should read:

```
require 'digest'
hashed = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest("test")
path = "/myFile/%s" %hashed
```